# How can I play music in background while talking to another person

Tags: java, android, microphone

I am calling from phone A to phone B, phone A has an app through which I call phone B, I want my voice to merge with music so phone B can hear it too.

I have implemented soundpool and mediaplayer but that doesn't seem to work.

```
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 0);

        // Load the sound effects.
        babycryId = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.baby_cry, 1);

        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
                Log.d("SOUND POOL", "SOUND LOADED");
                soundPool.play(babycryId, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, 100, 1);
            }
        });
```

Reference app: https://www.noise-me.com/